# Limit the DataContainer's height and width

Tags: apache-flex

I wish to have a scroller to limit the height of the SkinnableDataContainer, so that I can scroll down the item redenerer. There is the code I have try

```
<s:SkinnableDataContainer id="skinnableDataContainer" x="10" y="38" width="691" height="512"
                          creationComplete="skinnableDataContainer_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                          dataProvider="{getAllProductdetailResult2.lastResult}"
                          itemRenderer="productItem"  scrollRect="{0,0,skinnableDataContainer.width,skinnableDataContainer.height}"> 

        <s:layout>  

            <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3" requestedRowCount="4" />
        </s:layout>



</s:SkinnableDataContainer>
```

But, the scrollRect have a error on it and I dont know how to make a rectangle class in the mxml.

I only need to have a vscroll bar and showing about one and a half itemredenerer. Any simple way to do this kind of job?

Comment: well to make a rectangle use scrollRect="{new Rectangle(0,0,width,height)}"

Comment: but not sure what you are asking about limiting to 1 1/2 item renderers?

Comment: actually, something like this [link]http://www.google.com.hk/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch&tbnid=1ZRcVegv0JiwdM:&imgrefurl=http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/airapi/2.0.0/qnx/fuse/ui/listClasses/TileList.html&docid=WeVMR1_R2lORIM&imgurl=http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/airapi/2.0.0/images/tilelist_167.gif&w=512&h=371&ei=50aTUICqMY6XiAfE5YCoDA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=819&vpy=127&dur=1957&hovh=191&hovw=264&tx=131&ty=75&sig=102540646765387936038&page=3&tbnh=117&tbnw=162&start=43&ndsp=30&ved=1t:429,i:288&biw=1280&bih=701[link]

Comment: and with a vscoll bar on the right hand side. Sorry, I dont know how to describe it. and, you method work but the scroll bar still not on the DataContainer. Ai....

Comment: ok I get your question now.  You need to wrap the <SkinaableDataContainer> in a <Scroller>.

Comment: I already find out how to do it. Just need to wrap a vscroll and the itemrenderer in a Hgroup container. Then, set the scrollbar viewport point to the item renderer. and , Your methods will  also work same principles.